# Is it possible to change the window border color of terminal in freya?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, themes, gtk, pantheon

[image: desktop]

I just want to make the `vim a.txt` to black and the background color of the title bar and the tab bar to silver.

Comment: Do you want the color only for this document or should the whole terminal color change independently from the document ?

Comment: The title bar and the tab bars should be silver while the text in both of them should be black. It should hold for every instance of the terminal